# .map is not a function in Angular 2 importing map operator doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is my code, I can't figure out why this is saying .map not a function. This is a generic method.

```
  public findTeamRoles(id: any, userId: any): Observable<any> {
let _method: string = "GET";
let _url: string = LoopBackConfig.getPath() + "/" + LoopBackConfig.getApiVersion() +
"/Programs/:id/findTeamRoles";
let _routeParams: any = {
  id: id
};
let _postBody: any = {};
let _urlParams: any = {};
if (userId) _urlParams.userId = userId;
let result = this.request(_method, _url, _routeParams, _urlParams, _postBody);
return result.map((instances: Array<Program>) =>
    instances.map((instance: Program) => new Program(instance))
);
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
 core.es5.js:1084 ERROR TypeError: instances.map is not a function
```

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the elements within `result` are not themselves arrays and therefore don't have a `map` method. (Or at least one element is not an array.) Perhaps you should have a close look at the elements within `result` using your debugger?

Answer (score 4):

There is only one possibility for that error. Map is a prototype function of **Array**, so that `instances` is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: The only answer that makes sense :) +1

Comment: *"Map is a property of Array in Ecmascript 6..."*. I'm pretty sure that `#map` was added in ES5.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wasn't thinking in what version has been added. I saw typescript and I thought in ES6.

Comment: Ok, but I'm getting id and userId and the debugger is not showing anything out of the ordinary

Comment: use `console.log(instances)` just before `instances.map` and see what's the value.

Comment: This was the value Object {assigned: Array(7), unassigned: Array(0)}

Comment: Should I just wrap that in an array?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error in my typescript file, where I was pulling some data from a service. And I knew that the `map` is a [prototype function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) of the `Array`. So I was just looking at the code and I found that I was missing an `await` keyword in my function. It is a small mistake.

**Before**

```
public async getAddressesBySupplierId(supplierId: string): Promise<IAddressData[]> {
        const addresses: IAddressData[] = this.spFilter.getItems({
            title: config.listNames.adress
        });
        const addressWithType = addresses.map(async (address) => {
        const addressType = await this.getAddressTypeById(address.AdressartIdId);
        return await this.mapAddressType(address, addressType);
    });
        return Promise.all(addressWithType);
    }
```

**After**

```
public async getAddressesBySupplierId(supplierId: string): Promise<IAddressData[]> {
        const addresses: IAddressData[] = await this.spFilter.getItems({
            title: config.listNames.adress
        });
        const addressWithType = addresses.map(async (address) => {
        const addressType = await this.getAddressTypeById(address.AdressartIdId);
        return await this.mapAddressType(address, addressType);
    });
        return Promise.all(addressWithType);
    }
```

As you can see that on the first code block, I was missing the `async` keyword on the second line (before the `this.spFilter.getItems` call).